# Is it possible to share a pointer between (non-inherited) processes?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, ipc

The case is simple I have two unrelated processes (Plain C++ written apps A and B, one is not a childprocess of the other one), and they operate on same shared memory object.

In process A, I create a handle representing a handle to GPU memory, which I want to access in process B. So basically I have a void pointer stored in the Shared memory object and uint_64 representing size of the memory backing the pointer.

In process B I successfully map to the same shared mem. and I obtain the handle from it and required mem. size, the both variables have **same** values as they had in process A. So until heree it seems good, the problem is that if I try to use the handle and import the memory it seems it is invalid.

From what I read the different processes have completely different memory mapping, so even if the value of the pointer is same, it can point to the completely different piece of memory. Is that really true? And if that is the case is there any way how to share pointers between (non parent->child) processes, in a way that the value in A points to same memory as in B?

Is it possible or not? I am on Windows and I am OK with platform specific solution.

Comment: "Is it possible to share a pointer between processes?': no; each process has its own memory map. '[non-inherited]': irrelevant.

Comment: No you cannot share pointers through shared memory. You can only share values using shared memory (value semantics). So you would need to copy the data your pointer points to into the shared memory (not the pointer to it)

Comment: Both comments above look like they could be turned into answers. The only reason I can think of not to is if this is considered a duplicate. Can either of you name one?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Hm, that is unfortunate, as there are no other data except the adress that provides the access to GPU allocated memory. Although thanks to both for info and clarification.

Comment: @Yunnosch: There was basically same question, but was specific to process->childprocess, so I was not sure, if in such a case are applied some special rules.

Comment: CJ_Notned, I was addressing the authors of the two comments; not criticising your question. Asking a duplicate question should be avoided if possible, but it is not considered evil if you do not find one. Well done checking beforehand however. ;-)

Comment: There are no duplicates, I didn't consider my reply to be interesting enough to be considered  an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, each process has its own memory map. A memory map is a list of memory regions mapping from virtual addresses to physical addresses, i.e. a list of (vm_start, physical_start, size) tuples (and possibly other fields such as permission flags).

Thus a pointer in process P1 operates on the same value as in process P2 iff the memory map in these processes is the same near the pointer. This is not the case by default, and if you need it, you need to add the same entry (with the same physical_start) to the memory map of both processes. This should be possible using some Windows API functions, even for memory shared with the GPU. How exactly to do it, I don't know.

Without setting it up, process P2 will typically abort with an error if a pointer from process P1 is used, or P2 will silently modify an unrelated value (causing problems in the future of process P2).

The parent-child relationship of the processes is not relevant.